# Incorrect operation of pair conditions in if\else

Tags: python, list, replace

I welcome everyone. The situation is as follows - in a list whose values are from 0 to 24, it is necessary to replace multiples of 3 digits with 'a', multiples of 4 - with 'b', multiples of both the 3rd and 4th - with 'c'.
Simple solution -

```
y = list(range(0,25))

def some(x):
    decim_3 = 3
    decim_4 = 4
    for i in x:
        if i % decim_3 == 0:
            i = 'a'
        elif (i % decim_4) == 0:
            i = 'b'
        elif i % decim_3 == 0 and i % decim_4 == 0:
            i = 'c'
        else:
            i = i
        print(i)
```

the solution correctly changes the value according to the first two conditions, but not working with third condition

```
some(y)

a, 1, 2, a, b, 5, a, 7, b, a, 10, 11, a, 13, 14, a, b, 17, a, 19, b, a, 22, 23, a
```

Comment: Consider which branch is taken if ``i % decim_3 == 0`` is true. Consider whether it then matters whether ``i % decim_4 == 0`` is true as well.

Comment: Change the order. `elif` will not be evaluated if a previous `if`/`elif` block was executed

Comment: Heads up that this is basically a FizzBuzz. There are... *many* solutions and templates for this available, both on [so] and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you use if/else, which means that as soon as the first condition is True, the rest of the conditions will not be checked.

So here, as soon as you check if 12 is divisable by 3, it will turn i into 'a' and not check the other conditions.

Your solution is to put the most specific condition first (which is multipliers of both 3 and 4) like this:

```
def some(x):
    decim_3 = 3
    decim_4 = 4
    for i in x:
        if i % decim_3 == 0 and i % decim_4 == 0:
            i = 'c'
        elif i % decim_3:
            i = 'a'
        elif (i % decim_4) == 0:
            i = 'b'
        else:
            i = i
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should ask for the multiple of both in the first condition.

This way, even if the number is multiple of both, first condition is evaluated as true and ad if block is ended.

```
if i % decim_3 == 0 and i % decim_4 == 0:
        i = 'c'
    elif (i % decim_4) == 0:
        i = 'b'
    elif (i % decim_3) == 0:
        i = 'a'
    else:
        i = i
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly `if i % decim_3 == 0` will be triggered for multiples of 12, so you need to check that first:

```
if i % 12 == 0:
    i = 'c'
elif i % 3 == 0:
    i = 'a'
elif i % 4 == 0:
    i = 'b'
```

You don't need an `else` here: `i = i` is a no-op.

Another way you can do this:

```
i = [i, 'a', 'b', 'c'][(not i % 3) + 2 * (not i % 4)]
```

`not` transforms the result into a `bool`, which is a subclass of `int` that is always either zero or one. You can then turn the two tests into the bits of an index from 0 to 3 by shifting one of them (multiplying by 2 in this case). The equivalent index is

```
(not i % 3) | ((not i % 4) << 1)
```